# Indexing avro file to elasticsearch in bulk

Tags: python, elasticsearch, avro

I wrote this short simple script

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from fastavro import reader

es = Elasticsearch(['someIP:somePort'])
with open('data.avro', 'rb') as fo:
    avro_reader = reader(fo)
    for record in avro_reader:
        es.index(index="my_index", body=record)
```

It works absolutely fine. Each record is a json and Elasticsearch can index json files. But rather than going one by one in a for loop, is there a way to do this in bulk? Because this is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1. Use Elasticsearch Bulk API and `requests` python
2. Use Elasticsearch python library which internally calls the same bulk API

```
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    from elasticsearch import helpers
    from fastavro import reader
    
    es = Elasticsearch(['someIP:somePort'])
    
    with open('data.avro', 'rb') as fo:
        avro_reader = reader(fo)
        records = [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "record",
                "_id": j,
                "_source": record
            }
            for j,record in enumerate(avro_reader)
            ]
        helpers.bulk(es, records)
```

Comment: What's actions? What's j? I'm no expert and very new to this, but as i copy and paste this, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. What is j supposed to be?

Comment: @OriaGruber I'm creating a list of all the records and at once I'm sending it. So, I have named my variable `records`. You should pass `records` to the `bulk` function with the connection variable

Comment: I realize that. I meant what's the j at the "_id" part. I changed your code to "for j, record in enumerate(avro_reader)", hopefully it will work

Comment: @OriaGruber If you are bulk indexing, then you will have to give your ids. Hence, I'm taking the record index in the list as `j`